# Share Page Object classes between appium and webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, pageobjects

i wanted to know how can I get to share the same objects between Selenium WebDriver and Appium's AndroidDriver and IOSDriver.

Right now i have duplicated the page objets to make the mobile version of my code with appium, but i'm sure that i can make them in a way that i can share the same code because the main different appart of some elements in the page, is the constructor.

In the AppiumDriver PO:

```
public class ObjHomePageMobileWeb {

    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    protected By element = By...;

    public ObjHomePageMobileWeb(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

And in the WebDriver PO i have:

```
public class ObjHomePageWebPc {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected By element = By...;

    public ObjHomePageWebPc(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

In my tests suites, i instantiate this PO with the corresponding driver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating a single PO and using it in both situations? What was the result? Doesn't `AppiumDriver` inherit from `WebDriver` or some variant?

Comment: It worked... lol, I didn't even thinked it will work...